# Prevent CSS & jQuery (Mobile) from getting cached

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, caching

I have a site that I have limited control over. There is an existing template that is using jQuery Mobile v.1.0a3 along with all custom styles.

I am creating a new template - within the same site - that is using all updated libraries of jQM and jQM css (via cdn).

When I navigate directly to my new page, everything is great; it looks/functions perfectly. However if I start at my new page, then navigate to any existing (older) page - the old page is inheriting the cached file(s) of the updated libraries. I am struggling to find a way to tell the system to completely reload everything.

For example, page "A" uses template "A", page "B" uses template "B". I am trying to figure out a way to have the system reload everything when navigating from "A" to "B" (or vice-versa). The paths to the css and js are different for each template.

I've tried setting cache-control meta data but no luck. Are there any other options?

Comment: How are these files being included? In a tag, or are they loaded through JS?

Comment: Do you have PHP at the server side. Then all you need to do is generate a random Alpha numeric value and put it at the end of the links, like this with the question mark. (http://mypage.html?123abc --- or your css files or anything that has a url. that way it would not find it in the cache and load a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I don't know if this is the correct way, but it seems to be working. Efficiency is in the drain, but this is the only thing I've found (so far) that is working like I need.

I've put this on every anchor tag that links outside of any given template:

HTML:

```
<a href="myLink" data-ajax="false">My Link</a>
```

So for any link that links from an old page to a new page (or vice-versa) will have that data attribute.